# Why is my code comment using the most CPU time?

Tags: c++, xcode, profiling, instruments

Ok, forgive the tongue-in-cheek question title, but when time profiling some code using instruments, it flags the most intensive operation as a comment . .

[image]

The function `gamma(float)` is never called, and the code above the screenshot is only used to fill a lookup table when the program is initialised. The profiling session is run for long enough to make the process of filling the lookup table negligible. Therefore, it is unlikely that the profiler GUI has just missed by a couple of lines.

Any idea what is going on, or what this information signifies?

Comment: A comment cannot take up any CPU time, period. So either your source<->code binding is wrong (i.e. it's pointing to a different/out-of-date source file), or it's off by a line - perhaps it's the line above the marked one?

Comment: It can also happen because of optimization

Comment: The profiler has to interpolate the location of the source line based on the program counter value acquired during sampling, since there is not a mapping for every byte of object code to its corresponding source line - this is not an exact process of course, so you don't always get the correct line.